# Export world with turtles' coordinates

Tags: export-to-csv, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am developing a model that loads an .asc topographic file to the view and then, I create some turtles and the model runs etc., etc..

I would like to know if it's possible to export the result of the simulation with turtle location into .asc or .csv. I have never done something like this so I really need help.

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. You haven't provided enough information to give you a specific answers, but you could look at the Output programming guide in the NetLogo documentation (see https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#output) and/or look at BehaviorSpace for batch simulation.

Comment: I have done export-world to generate a csv file. I have something like turtle 1 -> patch {x, y}. I dont want patch coordinates, I want the original latitude and longitude coordinates from which I loaded an .asc file whose coordinates were converted to patch {x, y} coordinates.

A file that I loaded has the following format: longitude, latitude, variable.
ex: 2.2323832, -0.3323232, 32.2
When I load it to Netlogo I have, p.e.: patch {322,334} with variable = 32.2
I would like to reconvert the patch variables to the corresponding latitude and longitude from the original file

Comment: I think the problem may be in loading the files and setting the coordinate system.

Comment: I found something interesting. If I type ,p.e. 
show gis:envelope-of turtle 100 on Netlogo command center the output is [-5.344978449916806 -5.344978449916806 36.786798929201325 36.786798929201325], which is probably the "real" coordinates of the turtle.
Is there a way to save the output of this command applied to every turtle and save it on a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the output programming guide in the NetLogo documentation (see ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#output). You want something like (not tested):

```
file-open "filename.csv"
ask turtles
[ file-type xcor filetype ", "
  file-type ycor filetype ", "
  file-print myvariablename
]
file-close
```

This will put each turtle's information on a separate line in the file, with the x-coordinate, y-coordinate and the value of the variable called myvariablename. A comma is between each.

The primitive you have found `export-world` saves everything, not just the information you want and not in csv format.

Comment: Ok, I've come with this: 
`file-open "filename.csv"
  ask bees
  
  [
    
    file-type gis:envelope-of bee who
    file-type ","
    file-type who
    file-type ","
    file-type tipo
    file-type "\n"
  ]
  file-close`

This is almost what I want, except that gis:envelope-of retrieves a list with the following format: [ x1, x2, y1, y2]. Do you know how to use this primitive to retrieve a list with the format: [x1, y1] , i.e. print only x1 and y1 to the file?

Answer (score 0):

To put @JenB 's answer in context this is the way I found to solve the problem:

`file-open "filename.csv"
  ask bees

[

```
file-type item 1 gis:envelope-of bee who
file-type ","
file-type item 3 gis:envelope-of bee who
file-type ","
file-type who
file-type ","
file-type tipo
file-type "\n"
```

]
    file-close`

This will create a csv type with the following format:

`[latitude, longitude, number of the turtle, tipo (a turtle attribute)]`